# Finding a power series

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

I am suppoused see the power series for

$$ f(x) = f(0) + \int_0^x \left(1 + \dfrac{1}{2} f(s) \right)ds $$
for $x \in \left[0, 1\right]$ and $f(0) = 1$.

Then if I take

$$
\begin{align}
f_0 &= 1 \\
f_1 &= 1 + x + \dfrac{1}{2}x \\
f_2 &= 1 + \dfrac{3}{2}x +\dfrac{3}{8}x^2 \\
f_3 &= 1+\dfrac{3}{2}x + \dfrac{3}{8}x^2 + \dfrac{x^3}{16}
\end{align}
$$

I know it involves exponential but I cant see what exactly it's a power series for.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you make you first equation $f(x)=f(0)+\ldots$ clearer? Is it $(1+.5f(s))ds$? I guess it is. You should add parentheses.

Comment: What is $T$? Should your first equation be $Tf(x)=f(0)+\ldots$?

Comment: @julien hey, sorry about that, hopefully it clears things up, im "suppoused" see what the series is from $f_0,f_1,f_2,f_3$

Comment: @bobdylan Can't you differentiate both sides to get a differential equation and then solve it to find $f$ explicitly? Then it should be easier to get the power series.

Comment: How do you define $T$? From the first terms of your sequence, I understand it is $Tf(x)=f(0)+\int_0^x(1+.5f(s))ds$. If this is the case, please edit.

Comment: @julien my apologies, i misunderstood the concept, T wasnt necessary in this question, this question dictates that i must not use the ode method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I finally understood the question...We are not allowed to differentiate and solve the ODE.

Assume you have a degree $n$ Taylor expansion
$$
f(x)=T_n(x)+O(x^{n+1}).
$$
Then
$$
f(x)=f(0)+\int_0^x(1+\frac{1}{2}f(s))ds
$$
$$
=1+x+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^xT_n(s)ds+\frac{1}{2}\int _0^xO(s^{n+1})ds
$$
$$
=1+x+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^xT_n(s)ds+O(x^{n+2}).
$$

This means that there is a first order linear recurrence relation on the Taylor polynomials:
$$
T_{n+1}(x)=1+x+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^xT_n(s)ds\qquad T_0(x)=1.
$$
Writing
$$
T_n(x)=1+a_1x+\ldots++a_{n}x^n
$$
this yields
$$
1+a_1x+\ldots+a_{n+1}x^{n+1}=1+x+\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{a_1}{4}x^2+\ldots+\frac{a_n}{2(n+1)}x^{n+1}.
$$
Equating the coefficients, we get:
$$
a_k=\frac{a_{k-1}}{2k}\qquad\forall k\geq 2\qquad a_1=\frac{3}{2}.
$$
An easy induction shows that
$$
a_k=\frac{3}{2^{k}k!}
$$
So 
$$
T_n(x)=1+\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{3}{2^kk!}x^k
$$
which converges to 
$$
1+\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{3}{2^kk!}x^k=1+3\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{(x/2)^k}{k!}=1+3(e^{x/2}-1)=3e^{x/2}-2.
$$

Comment: @bobdylan Is this with you wanted? Taylor expansion without differentiating?

Comment: Absolutely, thanks so much for your time dude

Comment: @bobdylan Ah, great then. You're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

You could of course consider taking the derivative of both sides and get the equivalent equation:

$$f'(x) = 1+ \frac{1}{2} f(x)$$
$$f(0)=1$$

The solution to this equation is

$$f(x) = A e^{x/2} + B$$

You can find $A$ and $B$ from the equation and initial condition.  This solution should give you some perspective on your method of extracting the series.

Comment: I think there is a mistake in the first line. It should be $Tf(x)=f(0)+\ldots$, I think...

Comment: I don't see a mistake.  Taking the derivative is very straightforward...unless I have missed something.

Comment: I am not saying you made a mistake. I am having a hard time understanding the question...

Comment: My apologies, @julien.  Lots of misunderstanding going on.  I just looked at the equation and ignored all of the $T$ stuff.

Comment: This question is not clear at all. At some point, it seemed that we had to do that without ode...Look what this made me do...